# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' in include

Tags: ejs

Hi I tried everything but this error always comes up

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' in `<% include ../partials/header %>`
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the dashes were missed: <%- and -%>

> Specifically <% include /included %> style includes were removed and must be changed to <%- include('/included') -%>

Please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/1392#issue-693480754)

Comment: Thank you sooooo much. 
It works now perfectly. <%- include('../partials/header') -%>
Ineed some emojis for love here!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you sooooo much Oumaima.
It works now perfectly.

```
<%- include('../partials/header') -%>
```

Ineed some emojis for love here!